# Installing puppet from source b/c Ubuntu versions via apt are old

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

Is my only option to get version 2.6.8 via downloading from source?

My ubuntu version that was installed was 2.6.1 via apt-get.

If I download it by source, then I have to write the start/stop/restart scripts myself, was hoping to avoid this scenerio.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu version is identical to the Debian version, so this is an example of a package that is safe to pull directly from the Debian repositories.

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/puppet/puppet_2.6.8-1_all.deb

Comment: So do I have to update my source list to do this?  or can I somehow use apt-get using that url?

Comment: You can try downloading the package and installing it with `dpkg -i debfile.deb`, but it won't pull dependencies - if you need those you can add the Debian source to your `sources.list`. See http://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-apt-pinning just in case.

Comment: Eduardo is correct, but that way lie monsters.  Pinning is complex and can deliver unexpected results if you're not sure what you're doing.  I haven't looked over the dependency list for the debian package, but you *should* be able to just wget that URL and `dpkg -i` the file it downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to install the puppet ruby gem and the deb packages it depends on.

These being irb libopenssl-ruby libreadline-ruby rdoc ri ruby ruby-dev

Taken from "Setting up Puppet on Ubuntu 10.04" by George Ornbo.
http://shapeshed.com/journal/setting-up-puppet-on-ubuntu-10-04/

I'm still at the beginners phases with puppet too, hope this helps.

Update: puppet 2,6.8 has issues with ruby 1.9, these will be fixed in puppet 2.7.0
See: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7648

Answer (score 0):

I've installed a newer puppet from the repository at http://apt.puppetlabs.com/. A simple script for Ubuntu (codename *precise*) could be:

```
rsync -av --copy-links --del rsync://apt.puppetlabs.com/packages/apt/ /var/apt/
sudo dpkg -i /var/apt/pool/precise/main/p/puppet/puppet-common_2.7.14-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i /var/apt/pool/precise/main/p/puppet/puppetmaster-common_2.7.14-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i /var/apt/pool/precise/main/p/puppet/puppet_2.7.14-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
```

Hope this helps!